# Nearby cycle functor for a family of stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, sheaf-theory, perverse-sheaves

Let $B$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ (or rather a germ of it at a point $b\in B$). Let $f\colon E\to B$ be a proper flat family of stable curves with smooth generic fiber. Assume that the fiber $f^{-1}(b)$ is not smooth.

Let us consider the nearby cycle functor $\psi_f(\underline{\mathbb{C}})$ of the constant sheaf on $E\backslash f^{-1}(b)$ which is a complex of sheaves on the special fiber $f^{-1}(b)$. Outside of singular points it is a local system of rank 1. If I understand correctly, at singular points $\psi_f(\underline{\mathbb{C}})$ is concentrated at two degrees, 0 and 1 (after appropriate normalization). I expect that the sheaf cohomology in degree 0 has rank 1 (am I wrong?). Let us denote by $r$ the rank of the sheaf cohomology in degree 1.

**Question.** What are the possible values of $r$?

In a simple example I know $r=1$, but can one have $r>1$?

I apologize if this question is not of a research level, I am not an expert in the field.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\bar M_E = \varepsilon_* \mathbb{Z}$ where $\varepsilon: \tilde E_b\to E_b$ is the normalization map of the special fiber. If the irreducible components $X_1, \ldots, X_r$ of the special fiber are smooth (i.e. have no self-intersections) then $\bar M_E \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \mathbb{Z}_{X_i}$.

Let $\bar M_{E/B}$ be the quotient of $\bar M_E$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ so that we have an extension
$$ 0\to \mathbb{Z} \to \bar M_E \to \bar M_{E/B}\to 0. $$

Then there are canonical isomorphisms
$$ \mathbb{Z} \cong \psi_f^0(\mathbb{Z}) \quad\text{and}\quad \bar M_{E/B}(-1) \cong \psi_f^1(\mathbb{Z}). $$
Here $(-1)$ means Tate twist i.e. tensor product with $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \mathbb{Z}$.

In particular, the local system $\psi_f^0(\mathbb{Z})$ is constant, and $\psi_f^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is just (but noncanonically) a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ at each node.

**EDIT.** Some references: This goes back at least to SGA7 where nearby cycle complexes were originally defined. I highly recommend Illusie's survey *Autour du theoreme de monodromie locale* in Asterisque 223 (in particular, section 2.1), although it is much more general than what you need.. Later it was realized by Kato, Nakayama, and others that one can explicate in a very simple way nearby cycles in a semistable situation using logarithmic geometry (the notation $\bar M_E$ I used above was motivated by this). For this, there is another nice survey by Illusie in another Asterisque. Also see 4.9 of [this](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~illusie/Illusie-Grothendieck-nearby-cycles5.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks. Do you have a reference for this fact?